# expose multiple tcp port from ingress controller in aks

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

As per this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic , I can apply route for https based application . Since I have TCP based application which I need to expose via ingress loadbalancer.
**Is there any document which provides steps to implement tcp route?**

Comment: Have you seen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/http-application-routing ?

Comment: I had gone through this document and it explains configurations related to http route but I feel there should be a similar document which should let us know for tcp route as provided in https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md

Comment: With this helm command - helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set tcp.9000="namespace/podname:9000"  sets all the values specified in the document https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md, but still not able to access port 9000

Answer (score 2):

**helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set tcp.9000="namespace/service:9000"**

To expose tcp port we need to use above command which will add this port i.e. 9000 to the load balancer, also the nginx controller routes the incoming request on that port to the provided service eg namespace/service:9000. Since the service is bound to a respective pod provided in the helm command, tcp route works.

To expose multiple ports and its respective service we need to use YAML with multiple ports with respective service as below
tcp:
"9000": "namespace/service:9000"
"9001": "namespace1/service:9001"

Then we need below command to apply tcp route for all of the ports

**helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -f values.yaml**

Comment: Hi @Pankaj kumar jha, Could you please share `values.yaml` and what does mean by `"namespace/service:9000`?

Comment: tcp: 
    "100": "galore/galore-chart-timescale:100"

Comment: This above string is in values.yaml and "namespace/service:9000" is service name within namespace with port

Comment: Yeah. I was able to figure out that and works like charm. Thanks man for your post and answer.